# google custom search determine when script is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I'm using google custom search in the simplest possible form. I've just added the generated script and the the tag `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` on a view. Everything works as expected however I would like to be able to set the search term in the textbox myself and then trigger the submit. I can't figure out how to determine when the script below is loaded. Is there a way to modify the script so I can use the jQuery `then()` function?

```
(function () {
        var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })()
```

**UPDATE**

Well in the end I found some kind of solution, probably not the most elegant one, but it work. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.se/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("search", "1", { language: 'sv', style: google.loader.themes.MINIMALIST });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        var ctrl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx');
        ctrl.draw('cse');

        // you can do stuff here, like trigger a search as shown  below !!        

        ctrl.execute('<%=Request.QueryString["text"] %>');
    }, true);
</script>
```

Comment: @Palle I am trying to do the same thing. Could you please explain me how you did it? After your ctrl.draw('cse'), where are you passing the search results so that google knows what to search for?

Comment: ctrl.execute() will trigger the search. In this sample, a value from the querystring holds the search term  but you could do ctrl.execute('some term');

Answer (score 1):

I used an workaround for this. The script from google is creating a iframe with src attribute which contains the **&cx=** code and the term to search (**&q=**):

http://www.google.com/cse?cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxx%3Ac8u_ywvcjnw&ie=UTF-8&q=term+to+search&sa=Search&....

Using jquery, you could create an iframe with the attribute **src** set to be the above link.

Comment: @Silvanu I am trying to do the same thing you were able to do: I want to trigger the search once one of my other events is completed. How can I create an iframe using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else wants to do this a simpler way - I just used setInterval to poll for when it's loaded. search field:

```
 <gcse:searchresults-only gname='ap_search'></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

then just add a script tag under it:

```
javascript:
  var int=setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof google != 'undefined' && google.search.cse) {
      google.search.cse.element.getElement('ap_search').execute("#{@term}")  
      clearInterval(int)
    }
  }, 200)
```